# Getting error error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut while accessing annotation value inside an advice using ApectJ

Tags: java, annotations, aspectj

I'm trying to access custom annotation value inside an advice method but getting an error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:610)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut
```

Annotation declaration

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface Authorize {
    String[] entitlements() default "";
}
```

This issue happening with second argument in the method, if I removed the second argument application starts properly.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class AspectHandler{
    @Around(value = "@annotation(com.myorg.authorization.annotations.Authorize)")
    public void AuthValidator(ProceedingJoinPoint point, Authorize authorize) throws Throwable {
        String[] entitlements = authorize.entitlements();
        point.proceed();
    }
}
```

I tried with argNames argument, still it doesn't work

```
@Around(value = "@annotation(com.virtana.authorization.annotations.Authorize)", argNames = "authorize")
```

also tried

```
@Around(value = "@annotation(com.virtana.authorization.annotations.Authorize) && args=authorize")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. For unbound annotations it would be correct to use the fully qualified class name:

```java
@Around("@annotation(com.myorg.authorization.annotations.Authorize)")
public void validate(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable
```

For an annotation bound to an advice method parameter, you only use the parameter name as a reference:

```java
@Around("@annotation(authorize)")
public void validate(ProceedingJoinPoint point, Authorize authorize) throws Throwable
```

By the way: If your around advice returns `void`, it can only match methods with the same return type. If the target method returns anything else, your advice needs to return the result of `proceed()` or something other matching the actual return type.

Please also make sure to adhere to Java naming conventions. `AuthValidator` looks like a class name. Method names should not be nouns like `SomeObject` but verbal descriptions like `doSomething`, starting with a lower-case character.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this Kriegaex. If I use annotation bound, when I use custom annotation on any method, annotation advice method is not getting called. Example, I have Authorize annoation which I'm using for controller methods to check if user is authorized or not, when I call controller method annotation doesn't execute.

Comment: If you use my syntax instead of your two faulty variants, it should work. If it does not, the problem is in the part of your project you have **not** shared with us here. So please, publish an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub. I can take a look and help you solve your problem quickly by means of analysis instead of just speculation. Making your problem reproducible is a key ability for you as a software developer.

Comment: It worked, I tried "@Around("@annotation(authorize)")" same before posting question, it didnt worked, I might have missed something. But it is working as expected. Thanks